# Files different from running process and heroku run bash

Tags: bash, heroku

I accessed the dyno via `heroku run bash` and made a file `foo`. However, when I check from my app, it still cannot find `foo`. So I dug deeper by trying to install nginx on a dyno, turning on `autoindex`, and I can confirm that the files are different from what's accessed via `heroku run bash` and from nginx. Why is that? How do I put files to the filesystem where my running process is showing.

Answer (score 2):

When you issue `heroku run bash` a new dyno is created just for this one-off, and you are given access to it. Any file you create will "disappear" once your log-off, since the Heroku file-system is ephemeral.

That means the file-system is restored to its native state whenever a new dyno is created, or a dyno is rebooted. The "native" state is what's in your slug -- the "compiled" version of your app -- whatever is built by the build-pack after you "git push" to Heroku.

If you want a read-only file available to all your Dynos, either put it in your slug (for example: by including it in git, but also by using a different build-pack), or put it somewhere all your dynos can access (like a shared database, a Redis/Memcache instance, or most logically: S3).